# fusioncharts javascript render doesn't work inside liferay

Tags: liferay, fusioncharts

I am using liferay portal and displaying graphs on portlet...

The manual says the 3 js files(FusionCharts.js, highcharts.js and jquery.min.js) need to be placed in a folder and only FusionCharts.js needs to be included to render using javascript on ipad.

FusionCharts.js is loading other script on demand if it dont find it displays blank portlet.

I have included FusionCharts.js but it displays blank portlet

here is my code to display map

FusionCharts._fallbackJSChartWhenNoFlash();

```
                            var myChart = new FusionCharts("Column3D.swf", "myChartId11", "400", "300", "0", "0");
                            myChart.setDataXML(" <chart caption='Weekly Sales Summary' xAxisName='Week' yAxisName='Sales' numberPrefix='$'> <set label='Week 1' value='14400' /><set label='Week 2' value='19600' /><set label='Week 3' value='24000' /><set label='Week 4' value='15700' /></chart>");
                            myChart.render("chartContainer");
```

Is it possible to disable ondemand load and load the other 2 scripts manually?

Or anyone suggest any other fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply load the other scripts. The external script loader of FusionCharts takes care of that. Do it in the following order:

1. jquery.min.js
2. highcharts.js
3. FusionCharts.js